# Log analyzer for statistics (referring sites, referrers URLs) per day

Tags: nginx, log-files, awstats, analysis, goaccess

The main task of the analyzer - referring sites, referrers URLs. Logs are collected in one place from 3 nginx server. I install [awstats](http://www.awstats.org/) with a specific parameter LogFormat - all working fine, but the customer was not enough, we need statistics referring site and referrers URLs per day, awstats provides only for a month.

I found project [goaccess](https://goaccess.io/), but again, in the demo, I did not see the possibility of statistics for a day (or a certain period).

logstash + elasticsearch + kibana - never work with this soft, i need solution as fast as can)

Please, advise me the solution, thank you)

Comment: looks like logstash + elasticsearch + kibana works fine http://logz.io/blog/nginx-log-analysis/

Comment: i don't need so big solution for so small task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does Piwik cover your needs? You can download it for free from https://piwik.org/

Comment: Perfectly. Judging from the demo it's good for me, because they have a plugin log analyzer instead of the JS code. Thank you very much!